# Deleted Renderscript files, now getting errors

Tags: android, renderscript

I was playing around with Renderscript, and then I Deleted my .rs files from my source. I also deleted the raw folder in my res folder, that had a few .bc files, unfortunately now I keep getting:

```
[2013-08-18 15:16:43 - Zart3] error: error reading '/Users/me/workspace/Zart3/src/RSAttempt.rs'
```

I can't find any other traces, I've refreshed the app, etc, no luck. What step am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I closed Eclipse, and restarted. Still errors. After rebooting, opened Eclipse and no errors. *shrugs*.

Comment: It's called Eclipse because the occasions in which it functions as expected are about as prevalent as the occasions in which the moon blocks out the sun.

Comment: @Tonithy lol, I'm not sure about that.  I've at least seen the moon get blocked out in my lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

At build time, RenderScript compiles your `.rs` files to bytecode (`.bc`) in `PROJECT/res/raw/`, which is rolled into your `apk`. At runtime, the bytecode is compiled to executable binary by `libRSDriverArm.so`.

Sometimes Eclipse forgets to delete/update these bytecode files. In your case, it still had a recipe to build `PROJECT/res/raw/RSAttempt.bc` which depended on `RSAttempt.rs`. It was throwing that error because it couldn't find the dependency because you deleted it. Rebooting and opening Eclipse probably triggered a project clean, which occasionally (but not always D:) mops up those bytecode files.

In my case Eclipse just stopped compiling new bytecode files. This resulted in segfaults @ `0xdeadbaad`, `Calling invoke on bad script` and other errors that were useless/nobody has ever heard of, because I was trying to call functions from the (properly regenerated) java reflection classes that were not in the older version of the bytecode. Build time: *silence*.

Now I use a shell script to periodically delete `*.bc` throughout my workspace.